# Tensorflow CNN Error: Shape [-1,784] has negative dimensions?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I'm new to Tensorflow and trying to run mnist dataset with CNN. My Network is constructed  such as

1. 2 Convolution + Max Pooling
2. Fully Connected Layer
3. Softmax Layer
   Below is my tensorflow code of the model.

> ```
> def weight_variable(shape):
>     initial = tf.truncated_normal(shape, stddev=0.1)
>     return tf.Variable(initial)
>
> def bias_variable(shape):
>     initial = tf.constant(0.1, shape=shape)
>     return tf.Variable(initial)
>
> def conv2d(x, W):
>     return tf.nn.conv2d(x, W, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')
>
> def max_pool_2x2(x):
>     return tf.nn.max_pool(x, ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1], strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding='SAME')
>
>
> mnist = input_data.read_data_sets('MNIST_data/', one_hot=True)
> sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
> x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 784])
> y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 10])
> x_image = tf.reshape(x, [-1 , 28, 28, 1])
>
> W_conv1 = weight_variable([5, 5, 1, 32])
> b_conv1 = bias_variable([32])
> h_conv1 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(x_image, W_conv1) + b_conv1)
> h_pool1 = max_pool_2x2(h_conv1)
>
> W_conv2 = weight_variable([5, 5, 32, 64])
> b_conv2 = bias_variable([64])
> h_conv2 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(h_pool1, W_conv2) + b_conv2)
> h_pool2 = max_pool_2x2(h_conv2)
>
> W_fc1 = weight_variable([7*7*64, 1024])
> b_fc1 = bias_variable([1024])
> h_pool2_flat = tf.reshape(h_pool2, [-1, 7*7*64])
> h_fc1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(h_pool2_flat, W_fc1) + b_fc1)
>
> keep_prob = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
> h_fc1_drop = tf.nn.dropout(h_fc1, keep_prob)
>
> W_fc2 = weight_variable([1024, 10])
> b_fc2 = bias_variable([10])
> y_conv = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(h_fc1_drop, W_fc2) + b_fc2)
>
> cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(-tf.reduce_sum(y_ * tf.log(y_conv), reduction_indices=[1]))
> train_step = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(1e-4).minimize(cross_entropy)
>
> correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y_conv, 1), tf.arg_max(y_, 1))
> accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))
>
> tf.global_variables_initializer().run()
> for i in range(20000):
>     batch_xs, batch_ys = mnist.train.next_batch(50)
>     if i % 100 == 0:
>         train_accuracy = accuracy.eval(feed_dict={x: batch_xs, y_: batch_ys, keep_prob: 1.0})
>         print('step {:d}, training accuracy {:g}'.format(i, train_accuracy))
>     train_step.run(feed_dict={x: batch_xs, y_: batch_ys, keep_prob: 0.5})
> ```

Here are the stack info:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
/home/lv/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in _do_call(self, fn, *args)
   1138     try:
-> 1139       return fn(*args)
   1140     except errors.OpError as e:

/home/lv/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in _run_fn(session, feed_dict, 

fetch_list, target_list, options, run_metadata)
   1120                                  feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list,
-> 1121                                  status, run_metadata)
   1122 

/home/lv/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/contextlib.py in __exit__(self, type, value, traceback)
     88             try:
---> 89                 next(self.gen)
     90             except StopIteration:

/home/lv/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/errors_impl.py in 

raise_exception_on_not_ok_status()
    465           compat.as_text(pywrap_tensorflow.TF_Message(status)),
--> 466           pywrap_tensorflow.TF_GetCode(status))
    467   finally:

InvalidArgumentError: Shape [-1,784] has negative dimensions
     [[Node: Placeholder = Placeholder[dtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[?,784], 

_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]()]]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-32-d670cfa25269> in <module>()
      4 #        train_accuracy = accuracy.eval(feed_dict={x: batch_xs, y_: batch_ys, keep_prob: 1.0})
      5 #        print('step {:d}, training accuracy {:g}'.format(i, train_accuracy))
----> 6     train_step.run(feed_dict={x: batch_xs, y_: batch_ys, keep_prob: 0.5})
      7 

/home/lv/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py in run(self, feed_dict, session)
   1704         none, the default session will be used.
   1705     """
-> 1706     _run_using_default_session(self, feed_dict, self.graph, session)
   1707 
   1708 

/home/lv/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py in _run_using_default_session

(operation, feed_dict, graph, session)
   3961                        "the operation's graph is different from the session's "
   3962                        "graph.")
-> 3963   session.run(operation, feed_dict)
   3964 
   3965 

/home/lv/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in run(self, fetches, feed_dict, 

options, run_metadata)
    787     try:
    788       result = self._run(None, fetches, feed_dict, options_ptr,
--> 789                          run_metadata_ptr)
    790       if run_metadata:
    791         proto_data = tf_session.TF_GetBuffer(run_metadata_ptr)

/home/lv/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in _run(self, handle, fetches, 

feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
    995     if final_fetches or final_targets:
    996       results = self._do_run(handle, final_targets, final_fetches,
--> 997                              feed_dict_string, options, run_metadata)
    998     else:
    999       results = []

/home/lv/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in _do_run(self, handle, target_list, 

fetch_list, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
   1130     if handle is None:
   1131       return self._do_call(_run_fn, self._session, feed_dict, fetch_list,
-> 1132                            target_list, options, run_metadata)
   1133     else:
   1134       return self._do_call(_prun_fn, self._session, handle, feed_dict,

/home/lv/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in _do_call(self, fn, *args)
   1150         except KeyError:
   1151           pass
-> 1152       raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
   1153 
   1154   def _extend_graph(self):

InvalidArgumentError: Shape [-1,784] has negative dimensions
     [[Node: Placeholder = Placeholder[dtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[?,784], 

_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]()]]

Caused by op 'Placeholder', defined at:
  File "/home/lv/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/home/lv/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/home/lv/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ipykernel/__main__.py", line 3, in <module>
    app.launch_new_instance()
  File "/home/lv/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 658, in launch_instance
    app.start()
  File "/home/lv/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelapp.py", line 474, in start
    ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
  File "/home/lv/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/zmq/eventloop/ioloop.py", line 177, in start
    super(ZMQIOLoop, self).start()
  File "/home/lv/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/ioloop.py", line 887, in start
    handler_func(fd_obj, events)
  File "/home/lv/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/stack_context.py", line 275, in null_wrapper
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/lv/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 440, in _handle_events
    self._handle_recv()
  File "/home/lv/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 472, in _handle_recv
    self._run_callback(callback, msg)
  File "/home/lv/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 414, in _run_callback
    callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/lv/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/stack_context.py", line 275, in null_wrapper
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/lv/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 276, in dispatcher
    return self.dispatch_shell(stream, msg)
  File "/home/lv/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 228, in dispatch_shell
    handler(stream, idents, msg)
  File "/home/lv/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 390, in execute_request
    user_expressions, allow_stdin)
  File "/home/lv/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ipykernel/ipkernel.py", line 196, in do_execute
    res = shell.run_cell(code, store_history=store_history, silent=silent)
  File "/home/lv/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ipykernel/zmqshell.py", line 501, in run_cell
    return super(ZMQInteractiveShell, self).run_cell(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/lv/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2717, in run_cell
    interactivity=interactivity, compiler=compiler, result=result)
  File "/home/lv/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2821, in run_ast_nodes
    if self.run_code(code, result):
  File "/home/lv/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2881, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-5-c7318338c904>", line 1, in <module>
    x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 784])
  File "/home/lv/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/array_ops.py", line 1530, in placeholder
    return gen_array_ops._placeholder(dtype=dtype, shape=shape, name=name)
  File "/home/lv/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_array_ops.py", line 1954, in 

_placeholder
    name=name)
  File "/home/lv/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 767, in 

apply_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/home/lv/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2506, in create_op
    original_op=self._default_original_op, op_def=op_def)
  File "/home/lv/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1269, in __init__
    self._traceback = _extract_stack()

InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Shape [-1,784] has negative dimensions
     [[Node: Placeholder = Placeholder[dtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[?,784], 

_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]()]]
```

so, what is the problem? could somebody help me? thaks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sry,it's my bad , i just re-run the whole code, it works correctly.= =aha, i remember i run the `tf.global_variables_initializer().run()` twice before, it seems to be the reason causing wrong, i guess.

Comment: If this answer solved your issue, then please accept the answer. This helps others as it is clear that the question is closed and what exactly was it, that solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Some tensors don't support method `tensor.eval()` when you use the code `tf.placeholder()`.
If you don't use these tensor's `.eval()`,the error will not arise.